# Java Formatter class toString() doesn't work

Tags: java, tostring, formatter

I'm going through a Java book and now onto Formatter class outputting into a text file. I added in an extra line of code to test for the `toString()` towards the end of `addRecords()` but it does't work. Why is it so?

Furthermore, I am a bit confused about the `closeFile()` at `if (output != null)` then close the file. From my understanding is that I thought `output` has already formatted all the input into the text file how about it's still not null which leads me to try out the `toString()` at `addRecords()`.

Thanks in advance!

```
// Fig. 15.3: CreateTextFile.java
// Writing data to a sequential text file with class Formatter.
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.lang.SecurityException;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.FormatterClosedException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CreateTextFile
{
    private static Formatter output; // outputs text to a file

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        openFile();
        addRecords();
        closeFile();
    }

    // open file clients.txt
    public static void openFile()
    {
        try
        {
            output = new Formatter("clients.text"); // open the file
        }
        catch (SecurityException securityException)
        {
            System.err.println("Write permission denied. Terminating.");
            System.exit(1); // terminate the program
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException)
        {
            System.err.println("Error opening file. Terminating.");
            System.exit(1); // terminate the program
        }
    }

    // add records to file
    public static void addRecords()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.printf("%s%n%s%n? ",
            "Enter account number, first name, last name and balance.",
            "Enter end-of-file indicator to end input.");

        while (input.hasNext()) // loop until end-of-file indicator
        {
            try
            {
                // output new record to file; assumes valid input
                output.format("%d %s %s %.2f%n", input.nextInt(),
                    input.next(), input.next(), input.nextDouble());
            }
            catch (FormatterClosedException formatterClosedException)
            {
                System.err.println("Error writing to file. Terminating.");
                break;
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException elementException)
            {
                System.err.println("Invalid input. Please try again.");
                input.nextLine(); // discard input so user can try again
            }

            System.out.println(output.toString());
            System.out.print("? ");
        } // end while
    } // end method addRecords

    // close file
    public static void closeFile()
    {
        if (output != null)
            output.close();
    }
} // end class CreateTextFile
```

Here's the command line output:

Enter account number, first name, last name and balance.

Enter end-of-file indicator to end input.

? 100 Bob Blue 24.98
java.io.BufferedWriter@55f96302

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I added in an extra line of code to test for the `toString()` towards the end of `addRecords()` but it doesn't work. Why is it so?

It is working.  But it is not doing what you apparently think it does / should do.

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#toString--) for `Formatter.toString()` says:

> *"Returns the result of invoking `toString()` on the destination for the output."*

In this case, you have created a `Formatter` that writes to a `BufferedWriter`.  When `Formatter.toString()` calls `toString()` on a `BufferedWriter`, it doesn't give you back the stuff that you wrote to the file.  Rather, it returns you what `Object.toString()` would return.  That is described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--).

If you want your Java application print out what has been written to the file, you will need to open it, read it and copy the content to System.out.  And before you do that, you will need to `flush()` or `close()` the `Formatter`.

A simpler idea would be to look at the file using a text editor or the `less` command, or similar ... after the application has completed.   If the file is empty or shorter than you expect, make sure that your application *always* closes the `Formatter` before terminating.

Comment: I see....So what about the other question regarding `input != null` then close()`?

Comment: That part of your question doesn't make sense to me.   However, the problem may be that `closeFile()` doesn't actually get called at all.   You really should be using try-with-resources to ensure the formatter is always closed.

Comment: oh yes probably becoz i'm at the beginning of the chapter so the author tries to make it simple. anyways, it's the if statement that confuses me as how can `output` not equals to null?

Comment: It could be `null` if the call to `openFile()` was missing ... or if you added `output = null;` somewhere.

Comment: btw can I assume that the output object still holds onto all the input the user has keyed even though it has been outputed into a text file?

Comment: No you can't assume that.  It is not true.  If the data has been written to the file, there is a good change that the buffer contents have been overwritten.  And even if the data is still in the buffers (written or not!), the APIs do not provide any way to get data back from a BufferedWriter.

Comment: but in that case how come `output` is not equals to null? I thought after all the formatting to text file etc, output should be null?

Comment: What makes you think that `output` is actually `null`?  Add an `else` branch to that test and print something if `output` is `null`.

Comment: yup I do know that output is not null but I don't understand why it is not null because I think that it outputs all the keyed in data into the text file and therefore the object should be null.

Comment: Well that reasoning is completely wrong. Writing data, flushing, closing, and any other operation performed on an objject reference **will not** make it null.  The only way that `output` can become `null` is if something explicitly **assigns** `null`  to it.

Answer (score 1):

[BufferedWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) uses the default [toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) implementation from Object. The returned String contains the class name and the Objects [hashCode()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()).

If you want a string containing the output either use [String.format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) or a [StringWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html) to format your output before you write it to the file.

**Edit:** as mentioned by other answers the BufferedWriter is used internally by the Formatter when it is created with a filename. [Formatter.toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#toString()) calls BufferedWriter.toString() in this case.

Comment: To be frank i don't even see anything in the book mentioning about BufferedWriter but I will have a look at the doc thanks!

Comment: @Scorpiorian83 I missed that you use Formatter and not BufferedWriter directly. The Formatter.toString() calls BufferedWriter.toString() in this case.